# How to create an update button for a record using databinding in VB

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm pretty new to VB and I've been trying to create an update button for a Windows Form in VB. The data is displayed in a data grid along with text boxes for individual records. My aim is to enable the user to make a change in the textbox and press a button to update the database. I've been looking at how to do this but I can seem to find the answer anywhere. Below is a screenshot of the form along with the code.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOdf4.jpg)

```
Public Class Admin
#Region "MyCommand"
    Sub RecordPositionZ()
        With Me.BindingContext(Me.AzureDataSet.CustomerRequests)
            ' LBLPOSITION.Text = (.Position + 1).ToString & "from" & .Count.ToString & "Record Batabase !"
        End With
    End Sub

#End Region
    Private Sub Admin_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'AzureDataSet.CustomerRequests' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        Me.CustomerRequestsTableAdapter.Fill(Me.AzureDataSet.CustomerRequests)

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        CustomerRequestsBindingSource.MoveNext()
        Me.BindingContext(Me.AzureDataSet).Position += 1
        RecordPositionZ()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        CustomerRequestsBindingSource.MovePrevious()
        Me.BindingContext(Me.AzureDataSet).Position -= 1
        RecordPositionZ()
    End Sub


    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    End Sub




End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

(I have no idea if this works with azure, but here ya go maybe?)
if you have a dataset or tableadapter in your designer, right click it, and select Edit in Dataset Designer
[image]

Click the Table Adapter Here
[image]

and setup the update query in your properties and save it. The default may work right off the bat and seems to generate just by clicking it, however you may have to set up your own query. From there you can call your tableadapters.update() command.
[image]